# SQL statement SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY as identity_sid is executed as store procedure when I executed using JDBC through webapplication

Tags: java, sql-server-2008, jdbc

There is MSSQL server as database in backend and webapplication build java platform uses JDBC driver for database communication. In specific scenarion I have been trying to get auto generated id from Employee table after insert statement executing SELECT scope_identity subsequently on same connection.
But on some of the server after deployment code is breaking and instead of returning valid auto generated id in given scope it is returning NULL. When i debugged starting SQL profiling it does looks to be SELECT scope_identity statement is being executed as RPC - store procedure call and it is failing. 
I am queries how this conversion is being triggered from other server or from my local deployment it is working and SQL profiling I could see SELECT scope_identity call executed as batch and returning proper value.
Any help would be very approciated

Comment: Please use the standard JDBC facility for retrieving generated keys, don't use `SELECT scope_identity`.

Comment: Thanks Mark - Agree better to use standard jdbc provided retrieval options. But queries to know cause for this behaviour.